# Doctrine Query: how to sort by arbitrary ranking formula?

Tags: mysql, doctrine

For example:

```
DB table name: posts_table
DB table fields: id, view_count, like_count, created_at
```

I want to rank posts based on something like `(like_count*created_at)/view_count`. How do I do this in the form of a doctrine query?